# it it possible that absorption appears in the power spectrum of a non man-made system?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I mean some kind of system may dislike some special frequencies and there may be absorption lines.
Can somebody give some example? 
You can lots of emission lines below. But is it possible the PSD is just a continuum with several absorption lines?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_lines

Comment: @starblue You should make it an answer, it's pretty spot on.

Comment: sigh. I mean power spectral  density, not optical spectra!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, and probably off-topic.  What does it have to do with signal processing?

Comment: psd is widely used especially in signal processing. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density] Fraunhofer lines are off-topic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some kind of specific physical phenomenon, not really signal-processing related.